# What is the code in Harmonized System for NGL, LPG and LNG?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am trying to research trade statistics related to oil and gas using [BACI Database](http://www.cepii.fr/CEPII/en/bdd_modele/bdd_modele_item.asp?id=37). But I am confused about the product codes I should use.

I read an [article](https://blog.opisnet.com/ngl-or-lpg-or-lng) explaining the difference between Natural Gas Liquid, Liquefied Petroleum Gas, and Liquefied Natural Gas.[image]

Can anyone help with the corresponding HS code?